# New symbollicaly integral operator

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I have an u=u(x,t) that is an unknown function.
Suppose that the function u can be written as follows:

[image]
**

**...(Eq. 1)**

**

In here, $\Psi(x)$ is an Nx1 known vector, and  C is an NxN matrix. (N is an integer and superscript T   denotes the transpose of the matrix.)
I will integrate the both side of the Eq.1.

First, when I integrate the left hand side of the Eq.1,
It is classical integral of an unknown function. No problem here.

But in order to integrate the right hand side of the Eq.1,
I must define a new operator in order to accomplish the following two goals:

**First Goal**.

If we integrate Equation (1) with respect to **t** (from 0 to t ) and we use the above two assumptions about matrix P, **the Mathematica Module must give the following expression:**

[image]

**... (Eq. 2)**

where P matrix is defined as follows:

[image]
[image]

**Second Goal:**
If we integrate Equation (1) with respect to **x** (from 0 to x), and we use the above two assumptions about matrix P, **the Mathematica Module must give the following expression:**

$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t \partial x}=\Psi(x)^t.P^T.C.\Psi(t)$

**... (Eq. 3)**

Similarly; integrating the Eq. 1 two times with respect to x, we have

[image]
**... (Eq. 4)**

P.S. I have trying to  accomplish the goals since the last three days. But unfortunately,  I have no idea to share sample code.

Comment: Just cut-and-paste the code you've tried  (just as you've done with other questions).